# Line Break in Visual Force Page Table

Tags: visualforce, datatable

i did already a little research and could not find the right answer to it.
I have a visual force page with tables for an invoice template.
In the details for line items, i have the description field, which is a bit longer then the usual content for each row.
When I count the signs, i can count up to 50 signs within this line and everything after that is not shown, but i wonder if it is possible to change the line code to have the whole content. 
I already tried it with  around it, but that doesn´t solved it.
Thanks for any advice in advance

here is the line code

```
<td  style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:11px !important;    text-align:left; ">    <apex:outputText value="{!item.s2cor__Description__c}" />  </td>
```

and this is the header for the table

```
    <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;" width="100%">

   <apex:variable var="Index" value="{!1}"/>

     <apex:repeat value="{!Trade_Document.s2cor__Trade_Document_Items__r}" var="item">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser can wrap on either white space or a dash. So make sure your field have either white space or a dash. I tried with following code where description holds value like: `sdfsfsfsfsfs sfsfsfs sfsfs`

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
  <apex:form>
    <table width="10%">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <apex:outputText  value="{!Opportunity.Description}"/> 
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You have to provide a width to the table.

Comment: i made it that way in the line item, but it works great!  '<td width="30%"  style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:11px !important; text-align:left; ">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!item.s2cor__Detailed_Description__c}" />'